# Mule targeting where ForEach puts values

Tags: foreach, mule

Is there some way to target where a ForEach scope puts the value instead of the payload, much the way you can with an enricher?  I can't find any doc on this but thought I'd ask.

The use case is that I have a list of email addresses in a flow variable.  I want to email the payload coming into the flow to each addressee individually.  If I use a ForEach loop, I'm having to "switch in" the payload like this:

```
<set-variable variableName="emailBody" value="#[payload]"/>

<foreach collection="#[flowVars['mailTo']]">
    <set-variable variableName="addressee" value="#[payload]"/>
    <set-payload value="#[flowVars['emailBody']]"/>
  <!-- send the message here based upon the 'addressee' flow variable-->
</foreach>
```

Is there some way that each value of the iteration could be placed someplace other than the payload?  Or, am I approaching this all wrong?

Mule 3.3.1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the particular item in the collection (in the payload) in the current collection then just access that item using this property of the for each

```
counterVariableName="counter"
```